# before_find callback in ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback

My model has a string field, which actually used to store set of words. The order of the words is not important, so I use `before_create` callback to sort the words for uniqueness of the sets. Consequently I need corresponding callback for searching finding the string, i.e. such a callback would sort words in the incoming string and perform regular search. There is built-in `after_find` callback, but no before_ counterpart.

What is the best way to implement it? It should be triggered by the same methods as `after_find`. Or maybe there is another solution instead of callback?

**UPDATE:** there is a similar question [Implementing an ActiveRecord before_find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803532/implementing-an-activerecord-before-find),
but I decided to sort the words in the controller before storing in the database.